# Model Logic In Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, backend

I am working on the Laravel back-end and I have a some question. Can I put some logic methods to the the models? Get data in specific format, for example. And some like this:

```
public function getAllWithObjects()
{
    $all_photos = [];
    
    $all_readed = $this::all()->toArray();
    
    foreach($all_readed as $photo)
    {
        $all_photos[$photo["id_object"]][] = env("APP_URL")."/api/photos/".$photo["id"];
    }

    return $all_photos;
}
```

Or it's better put to the controller?

Looked for some videos and nothing else.

Comment: Controller, no logic should be saved on the models.

Comment: Photos should probably be a relationship, don't use `env()` anywhere outside of the `config` folder (it'll break), and you can use `url("/api/photos/".$photo["id"])` to ensure a fully qualified URL.

Comment: Logic that applies to a **single Model instance** is perfectly fine in a Model, but this code, which is loading all Models and their associated Image should be a Controller method (typically in the `index` method).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating an attribute to get the object id for each model

```php
public function getObjectIdAttribute(): ?string
{
  return $this->exists ? url("/api/photos/{$this->id}") : null;
}
```

and now your `App\Models\Photo` has an object_id property, `$photo->object_id`

Comment: Just a note that you might want to `object_id` to the model's `$appends` array.

Comment: Additionally, this syntax is for older versions of Laravel (`8.x` and below). In `9.x` and above, [it uses different syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) (this question wasn't tagged with a version, so your answer is perfectly fine, this is just for information purposes )

Comment: @TimLewis fixed typo, as for the version thing, I am aware but personally I still prefer the old syntax haha

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing a foreach statement to include the path of the image, you can actually insert it on the query using selectRaw and concat to joint the database field with a fixed stringg

```
$result = Photo::selectRaw(
          "CONCAT('/api/photos/',object_id) as path"
     )
     ->get();
```

Comment: Yikes. No. There are better ways of doing this that don't require dropping into raw unescaped queries, like an accessor.

Comment: id is a number and the string is controlled by the developer.

Comment: There remain much better options than dropping into raw queries. A `getPathAttribute()` accessor on the photo model that does `return url('/api/photos/' . $this->id);` would be much more sensible.

Comment: how about if you are not querying an item, you want to have the path for the whole result set?

Comment: Put `path` (from the accessor above) in the model's `$appends`, then something along the lines of `Model::all(['id'])->pluck('path')`.

Comment: if you have a short result set, but if you want a large result set, then you are adding a lot more process to get the same result, performance wise is not a good approach. You want to get the result then do some modifications to the returned collection..., instead of doing a concatenation? I always go for the KISS method.

Comment: selectRaw is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: We are not using any user provided values, the value come from the database and based on the user question is is an integer. The value that is in the concat is an static value provided by the developer.